# Count all characters in a file including \n etc

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

I am trying to iterate through a txt file and count all characters. This includes \n new line characters and anything else. I can only read through the file once. I am also recording letter frequency, amount of lines, amount of words, and etc. I can't quite figure out where to count the total amount of characters. (see code below) I know I need to before I use the StringTokenizer. (I have to use this by the way). I have tried multiple ways, but just can't quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Note* my variable numChars is only counting alpha characters(a,b,c etc) **edit posting class variables to make more sense of the code**

```
private final int NUMCHARS = 26;
private int[] characters = new int[NUMCHARS];
private final int WORDLENGTH = 23;
private int[] wordLengthCount = new int[WORDLENGTH];
private int numChars = 0;
private int numWords = 0;
private int numLines = 0;
private int numTotalChars = 0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

public void countLetters(Scanner scan) {
    char current;
    //int word;
    String token1;

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        String line = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        numLines++;

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line,
            " , .;:'\"&!?-_\n\t12345678910[]{}()@#$%^*/+-");
        for (int w = 0; w < token.countTokens(); w++) {
            numWords++;
        }

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            token1 = token.nextToken();
            if (token1.length() >= wordLengthCount.length) {
                wordLengthCount[wordLengthCount.length - 1]++;
            } else {
                wordLengthCount[token1.length() - 1]++;

            }

        }
        for (int ch = 0; ch < line.length(); ch++) {
            current = line.charAt(ch);
            if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z') {
                characters[current - 'a']++;
                numChars++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string.toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29), something like:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    numberchars += line.toCharArray().length;
    // ...
}
```

An Alternative would be to use directly the [string.length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    numberchars += line.length;
    // ...    
}
```

Using the BfferedReader you can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590854/395659):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), charsetName));
int charCount = 0;
while (reader.read() > -1) {
    charCount++;
}
```

Comment: String.length works almost. If I use scan.nextLine().length it throws a runtime error of Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1533). 
 at TextStatistics.countLetters(TextStatistics.java:28)
 at ProcessText.main(ProcessText.java:25)--- Instead I am just using numTotalChars += line.length(); This is almost there. It is still not capturing the \n (new line character) but I think I can just add 1 every time as it is capturing per a line.

Comment: That answer is very helpful also. For this project I wasn't allowed to use a buffered reader though. But it was good knowledge to learn anyways. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, don't all three of these solutions ignore line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

I would read by char from file with  BufferedReader and use Guava Multiset to count chars

```
BufferedReader rdr = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charSet);
HashMultiset < Character > ms = HashMultiset.create();
for (int c;
(c = rdr.read()) != -1;) {
    ms.add((char) c);
}
for (Multiset.Entry < Character > e: ms.entrySet()) {
    char c = e.getElement();
    int n = e.getCount();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but in the specs we can't use BufferedReader. But, thanks for you input. It got me thinking. :)